# Apex Class not creating new record

Tags: apex

I have an apex class that doe snot throw an error but does not create the new record.  I am trying to create a program__c record when the opportunity is 'closed won'.  I would like to be able to grab the id of the newly created record and then create another record using the new Id

```
 public void afterUpdate (SObject oldso, SObject newso)  {

    Opportunity oopp = (Opportunity )oldso;
    Opportunity nopp = (Opportunity )newso;

    List<Program__c> ProgramList=new List<Program__c>();
        if (nopp.StageName =='Closed Won') {
            Program__c p = new Program__c();
            system.debug('op ID:'+ nopp.id);
            p.Opportunity__c = nopp.id;
            p.Name = 'Test Name';
            insert p;
        }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with your code is that you create the opportunity list `oppty`, but it will always be empty so your for loop will not be hit. Likewise, since the list is empty, you can't possibly have an opportunity with a `StageName` of 'Closed Won'. I believe what you need to work with is passed into the method as arguments. Is this code called from a trigger? The `afterUpdate` name makes me think it is. You will want to bulkify your code if that's the case.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to stay with 1 trigger per object so I am passing the opportunity to the class 'OpportunityTriggerHandler.class,'Opportunity'.  I will take the insert out of the for loop as previously suggested.

Comment: By bulkifying, I mean you _want_ to pass all of your trigger Opportunities to your `afterUpdate` method at one time. Otherwise you're needlessly pushing and popping `afterUpdate` onto your call stack potentially 200 times (that's how many records can enter a trigger at once). What you want to do is pass all of the Opportunities into the method, build a `List<Program__c>` of Programs to insert, and then make only one insert call. See SFDC FAN's answer for example code.

Comment: I have updated the code based on SFDC fans example.  In the debug log the op variable is null as you stated.  Where I do see the opportunity id is  in the oldso and newso variables.  So how do I reference these variables in the for loop.

Comment: If you're only passing in one opportunity there's no reason for a list or a for-loop at all... I believe it's `newso` you want to check for "Closed Won" and make your `Program__c` accordingly

Comment: That worked. Thank you.  let me know if I need to close this post and address this additional question in another post, I have an object(place) that is a related record on the opportunity.  I want to create a new record when a new place record is created.  Should I create another class or can I use the same opportunity class and detect the creation of the new place record.  Just want to make sure I am approaching this correctly.

Comment: @Phuc, I would make a new question for that so you can provide all of the details. From the sound of it, you would want a `PlaceTriggerHandler` for a `Place.trigger` so that each object has only one trigger and the trigger has trigger handlers dedicated that object. [Some other tips here](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Code_Best_Practices)

If your question has been answered, don't forget to mark an answer as "Accepted".

Answer (score 0):

- Please check in debug Logs: Any error occurs while Inserting
- Dont write DML Statements inside the for Loop
- In your code oppty, doesnt have any Value
- oppty is empty,so for loop isnt iterating

  ```
  List<Program__c> ProgramList=new List<Program__c>();
   for (Opportunity op : oppty) {
  Program__c p = new Program__c();
  p.Opportunity__c = op.id;
  p.Name = 'Test Name';
  ProgramList.add(p);
  }
   try{
    insert ProgramList;
  }
    catch(exception ex){
     //catch error
  }
  ```

Comment: This is on the right track, but the `List<Program__c>` needs instantiated outside the for-loop, otherwise it gets destroyed and recreated with every iteration.

Comment: yes.I havent seen,mistake happened in hurry..its by mistake updated thanks

Comment: You should _never_ swallow exceptions with `System.debug()`. You do not need to check `isEmpty()` before performing DML.

Comment: okay. if i dont check it allows to insert empty List. if program list is empty. correct me if i am wrong

Comment: Inserting an empty list is a no-op.

Comment: okay sure . Thanks

Comment: if we use system.debug we can print the exception in debug logs . whats the problem while adding system.debug in catch statement

Comment: Exceptions are supposed to be **LOUD**. If you don't catch them, you get an immediate failure because your code is **broken**. That's how it is supposed to work. Catching and swallowing is a pattern that is almost always wrong. You already get the information you need to fix the problem when it fails; hiding the failure hurts you and your users.

Comment: thanks David...